# How to hide html tags on revision comparison pages?

Tags: posts, filters, revisions

I can see the html tags on post revision comparision page by default. Is there any filter or other method which will be helpful if I want to hide those html tags? I just want to use this comparision views to check content (text) changes I am not interested in any html formatting etc.

I want to make some simple php regex, but I don't know where.

Comment: It's impossible to separate HTML formatting changes from text changes. Posts are saved as HTML, so that's all that WordPress can compare. You could _maybe_ remove HTML tags from the comparison view, but then the comparison could appear misleading.

Comment: I understand this. I want to hide it on preview page (it will be easier to read). Is there any filter which I can use to make simple regex on this revision comparison page?